# Redefining CircuiTikz ground symbols to IEC 60417 variants

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Is it possible to change the CircuiTikz ground symbols to look more like the IEC 60417 ground symbols?

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell, the standard is not for schematics but rather for labels to be applied to equipment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is!

I changed the coordinates and line widths a little to make it look more similar:

[image]

The symbols you ask for are all *monopoles*, and they are defined in the file `pgfcircmonopoles.tex`.

Here is the code for the redefined monopoles:

```
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{ground}{
  \anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
  }
  \behindforegroundpath{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
    \pgfscope
      \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
      \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.6\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.6\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \endpgfscope
  }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{nground}{
  \anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
  }
  \behindforegroundpath{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
    \pgfscope
      \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
      \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.6\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.6\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0.9\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.6\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpatharc{0}{180}{0.9\pgf@circ@res@step}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \endpgfscope
  }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{pground}{
  \anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
  }
  \behindforegroundpath{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/ground/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
    \pgfscope
      \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
      \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.4\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.2\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.4\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.75\pgf@circ@res@step}}{0.9\pgf@circ@res@step}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \endpgfscope
  }
}

\pgfdeclareshape{cground}{
\anchor{center}{
    \pgfpointorigin
}
\behindforegroundpath{
    \pgf@circ@res@step=\ctikzvalof{monopoles/chassis/width}\pgf@circ@Rlen
    \pgfscope
      \pgfstartlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
      \pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{-1.5\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-1.00\pgf@circ@res@step}{-2.10\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.75\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.50\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ 0.75\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.50\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{ 0.50\pgf@circ@res@step}{-2.10\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{ 0.00\pgf@circ@res@step}{-1.50\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.25\pgf@circ@res@step}{-2.10\pgf@circ@res@step}}
      \pgfusepath{draw}
      \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfstartlinewidth}
    \endpgfscope
    }
}
\makeatother
```

You can save this as, say, newmonopoles.tex, and just `\input{newmonopoles}`. Or you can simply paste this code in your .tex file.

Here is the example document I showed above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

CircuiTi\emph{k}Z versions:\hfill
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{*{4}{C}}
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [ground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [nground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [pground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [cground] {};
\end{tabularx}

\input{newmonopoles}

ISO 7000/IEC 60417:\hfill
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\textwidth}{*{4}{C}}
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [ground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [nground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [pground] {};&
\tikz\draw (0,0) node [cground] {};
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: as fa as i can see, the main differences are in number of "ground" lines (four in `circuitikz`, and only three in standard. i would consider this as bug (symbols should consider ISO/IEC standards).

Comment: @Zarko Indeed, the differences are minimal. Only a few minor tweaks were needed to make them look like the picture the OP posted. I don't see it as a bug, though. The standards (made by reasonable people) don't demand petty minimalisms like line width and such, so the symbols in CircuiTi*k*Z are pretty much obey the standard. The changes I made were basically aesthetic to match the ones the OP asked for :)

Comment: you improve aesthetic appearance of symbols, but they still not comply with standard. standard are rigid with purpose (here is small difference, but with this symbol you can not design label for some equipment. label on equipment with such symbol will not pass compliance test for any of ISO/IEC standard). authors of package should be warned about this.

Comment: @Zarko Well, here in Brazil we don't use ISO/IEC (we use something that I prefer not to mention by name :P), so I can't really say anything precise about this. In this case, could you inform the authors of CircuiTi*k*Z then?

Comment: i doubt in this. all your electrical goods, which you exported, should complain at least to this standards :-). i will try to write to author of package.

Comment: You are right, the package should follow the according standards, i will implement the above code in the package.